# Jquery está somando os valores errado

Tags: jquery

Olá, quando eu seleciono um tratamento ele tem que pegar o valor em R$ e somar, para no final dar um total, porém se eu selecionar um option errado e ter que selecionar outro ele está somando isso, mas não deveria, pois dara erro no fical da soma.

```
      $(document).on('changed.bs.select', 'select.orcamento_tratameno', function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('option:selected', this).text();
    var value = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var valor = parseInt($('option:selected', this).attr('valor'));

    if(text != '' && value != '' && valor != '')
    {   
      if(newValue === true)
      {
        $('.orcamento_id_tratamento:last').val(value);
        $('.orcamento_tratamento_valor:last').val(valor);
        valorTratamento = (valorTratamento + valor);
        somaValores(valorTratamento);
      }
    }
  });     

});

function somaValores(valor)
{
  $('#subtotal').html('R$ '+formatReal(valor));
  $('#total').html('R$ '+formatReal(valor));
}

var valorTratamento = 0;
```

[image: Foto Tratamentos vis Dinamic]

```
/*ORÇAMENTOS------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var html_novo_tratamento = '';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="row align-items-center mt-3 dinamic">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <label  class="bmd-label-static">Plano</label>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <select class="selectpicker orcamento_plano" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="orcamento_plano[]" data-style="select-with-transition"  title="Plano" data-size="8" tabindex="-98">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </select>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <input type="hidden" class="orcamento_id_plano">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <label class="bmd-label-static">Tratamento</label>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <select class="selectpicker orcamento_tratameno" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="orcamento_tratameno[]" data-style="select-with-transition"  title="Tratamento" data-size="8" tabindex="-98">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </select>';        
html_novo_tratamento +=' <input type="hidden" class="orcamento_id_tratamento"> ';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <label  class="bmd-label-static">Dentes/Região</label>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <select class="selectpicker orcamento_tratamento_dente"  data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="orcamento_tratamento_dente[]" data-style="select-with-transition"  title="Dentes/Região" data-size="8" tabindex="-98"></select>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <label class="bmd-label-static">Valor</label>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <input type="text" class="form-control orcamento_tratamento_valor" name="orcamento_tratamento_valor[]" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-2 mt-3 text-right">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="div-actions" style="display: block; margin-left: 1em;">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <a href="#" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-dark btn-link remove">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 2em">delete</i>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </a>';                                                           
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="col-md-5 mt-3">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <label  class="bmd-label-static">Dentista</label>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="orcamento_dentista[]" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';                        
html_novo_tratamento +=' </div>';

$('.btn-novo-tratamento').on('click', function()
{ 
  $('.novo_tratamento').append(html_novo_tratamento);
  getAllPlanos(); // usado para popular os planos apos a adição da div 
  getTratamentoById(paciente_plano); // usado para popular os tratamentosapos a adição da div 
  getDentes(); // usado para popular os dentes/região apos a adição da div 
  $('.dropdown-menu .inner').perfectScrollbar();
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function()
{
  $(this).parents('div.dinamic').remove();
});
```

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Postei uma solução para você, espero que ajude. Me dê o feedback se funcionou ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está atribuindo o total da somatória ao valor base do tratamento, que é o parâmetro utilizado para a somatória, ou seja, a cada interação com este valor o mesmo será alterado.

```
if(newValue === true) {
    $('.orcamento_id_tratamento:last').val(value);
    $('.orcamento_tratamento_valor:last').val(valor);
    const total = valorTratamento + valor;
    somaValores(total);
}
```

### EDIT

Para somar os inputs que são adicionados dinamicamente pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
if(newValue === true) {
    $('.orcamento_id_tratamento:last').val(value);

    const $valores = $('.orcamento_tratamento_valor');
    $valores.last().val(valor); //Adicionar o valor no último input criado
    let total = 0;

    //Iterar cada input contido na coleção e somar cada valor encontrado
    $($valores).each(function (index, element) {
        total += parseFloat($(element).val());
    });

    somaValores(total);
}
```

Comment: No primeiro momento funcionou, porém quando adiciono as divs dinâmicas ele só pega o ultimo valor. Não sei se ficou claro.

Comment: Vou adicionar uma foto para você se basear melhor.

Comment: adicionei uma foto para você ver.

Comment: Se na primeira div eu boto testes testes no tratamento, porém eu errei e preciso trocar, ele mantem o valor e soma com o outro, porem não podia

Comment: Fugiu dos códigos que tenho :(

Comment: Dê uma olhada na atualização que fiz @JoséLuis